# Rails - how to render two identical forms but with different element IDs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to have two *almost* identical forms on a single page and use a partial for generating both with a render call.

```
<%= render 'form_template', data: @categories_one %>
<%= render 'form_template', data: @categories_two %>
```

The problem lies in their only difference - both forms use f.collection_select to provide dropboxes with categories for the user.

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, data, :id, :name %>
```

which creates two different forms with identical IDs for the SELECT tag, breaking my forms, and I would like to avoid that. But how can I do that?

Comment: According to the documentation (http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) `collection_select` helper doesn't set an id. Can you post the form partial code, and the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `:namespace` parameter to the `form_for`

> A namespace for your form to ensure uniqueness of id attributes on form elements. The namespace attribute will be prefixed with underscore on the generated HTML id.

Comment: Genius! 
<%= render 'form_template', namespace: "unique_id_prefix" %>

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-collection_select) for `collection_select`, you'll see that its last argument is for HTML options. So you can do this:

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, data, :id, :name, {}, {:id => "different_css_id"} %>
```

Since you said this is called within a partial though, from your identical render calls, you can pass along a variable to toggle this behaviour.

```
# Render calls
<%= render 'form_template', data: @categories_one %>
<%= render 'form_template', data: @categories_one, :locals => {:use_other_id => true} %>
```

And then use that flag in your partial.